# i can't sign my manifest using mage visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, manifest, mage

i'm trying to sign my manifest using mage as described in this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce?view=vs-2022#re-sign-the-application-and-deployment-manifests
but when i run the command it's says:
'mage' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: 2. Open the Visual Studio command prompt

Comment: didn't help ,still came up: mage' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: is there maybe a package that is needed to download?

Comment: any help please